# Define each of the following prolog predicates given the following information

Tags: prolog

[image]

please define only the following predicates:

- ancestor(X, Y)
- common_ancestor
- closest_common_ancestor
- ancestorList

So far I have doen parent, ancestor, common ancestor and closest common ancestor but I need help with the ancestor list part.

```
parent(john, jim).
parent(john, mary).

ancestor(Ancestor, Person) :-      % Rule 1: Base case
      parent(Ancestor, Person).

ancestor(Ancestor, Person) :-      % Rule 2: Recursive case
      parent(Parent, Person),
      ancestor(Ancestor, Parent).

common_ancestor(X, Y, Z) :- ancestor(X, Y), ancestor(X, Z).

closest_common_ancestor(X, Y, Z) :- common_ancestor(X, Y, Z),  not(common_ancestor(Y, X, Z)), not(common_ancestor(Z, X, Y)).

ancestorList(X, Y, L) :-
```

Answer (score -1):

ancestorList/3 returns a list of ancestors.

You can get ancestors with ancestor/2 as separate solutions (by backtracking you get all of them). So you need to collect these instances into a list.

This is a job for bagof (Superman?).